# Add ng-click does'nt work on directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have such directive:

```
app_directives.directive("multiNavigation", ['$compile',function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            menu: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/views/layout/miltiLevelNav.html',
        compile: function (el) {
            var contents = el.contents().remove();
            var compiled;
            return function(scope,el){
                if(!compiled)
                    compiled = $compile(contents);

                compiled(scope, function(clone){
                    el.append(clone);
                });
            };
        }

    };

}])
```

But when I in template try to add ng-click - it does'nt work. 
.
If add ng-click out directive html it works fine.

Comment: Show how you add ngClick.

Comment: You have an isolated scope directive, likely the method you are calling is not within scope is why ( defined in controller but not passed to directive)

Comment: i add ng-click in directive template:
<span ng-click="addPageToList(item.id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>

Comment: @elpofigisto, where is `addPageToList` defined?

Comment: @NewDev in controller.

Comment: @elpofigisto, the View controller that hosts the directive? Well, then it's obviously not going to work since you have an isolate scope. What is exposed on the outer scope is not visible, unless you use `$scope.$parent`, but then I would argue that you should redesign your directive such that it would provide a callback with `"&"`